# Ionic Angular Firestore: refresh list after deleting an element

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, ionic5, angular11

I can't manage to refresh my list of elements after I delete an item.
And, what I DO NOT understand: why does it work after adding an element. What's the difference?
I looked for multiple solutions, but I didn't find a good one.

My service

```
addWord(word: Word) {
    db.collection('words').add({
      name: this.toolsService.upperFirstletter(word.name),
      description: word.description
    })
      .then(() => {
        this.toastService.toastSuccess(`Le mot ${word.name} a bien créé !`);
      })
      ...
    this.emitWords();
  }

deleteWord(word: Word) {
    db.collection('words').doc(word.id).delete()
      .then(() => {
        this.toastService.toastSuccess(`Le mot ${word.name} a bien été supprimé !`);
      })
      ...
    this.emitWords();
  }

emitWords() {
    const listWords: Word[] = [];
    const wordCollection = db.collection('words').orderBy('name', 'asc').get();
    wordCollection
      .then((querySnapShot) => {
        querySnapShot.forEach((doc) => {
          listWords.push(
            new Word(
              doc.id,
              doc.data().name,
              doc.data().description
            )
          );
          this.listWords$.next(listWords.slice());
        });
      })
    ...
  }
```

It works with `add()` but it doesn't with `delete()`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have enabled offline capabilities for `firestore` don't use `then` or `await`. Just run your code as if it's sinchronous:

```js
addWord(word: Word) {
    db.collection('words').add({
      name: this.toolsService.upperFirstletter(word.name),
      description: word.description
    })
     
        this.toastService.toastSuccess(`Le mot ${word.name} a bien créé !`);
      
      
      ...
    
  }

deleteWord(word: Word) {
    db.collection('words').doc(word.id).delete()
      
        this.toastService.toastSuccess(`Le mot ${word.name} a bien été supprimé !`);
        
      
      ...
   
  }
```

Ant for a realtime listener use `onSnaphost` like here:

```js
db.collection("words").orderBy('name', 'asc')
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        var words = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            words .push(doc.data().name);
        });
        console.log("Current cities in CA: ", words.join(", "));
    });
```

That way you don't need to call `emitWords` each time you change something.

Comment: But that's what i do in the delete(). For adding a word, it's working. Even if the emit() is outside ``then``. You're right, it's better of course if the emit() is inside then but even that, the refresh doesn't work every time.

Comment: I have update my answer. Can you try it with the new approach.

Comment: OK, I think it's working, thanks a lot ! So, I'll replace my emit() (.then & .catch) by onSnapshot. But if I want to do this asynchronously, how can I do that plz ? And when I add an element, why does the asynchronous method work (the list is refreshed) ? Is there a difference between adding and deleting an element in a firestore collection ?

Comment: Firestore is working by default offline so you don't need to use asynchonous calls. The data is added in a synchronous way and synced when the user has internet. If he has it already it happens quite fast and if not it happens when he regains connection. Regarding the realtime listeners there is no difference. Maybe check how you handle state changes.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot Tarik !